# Why is Heroku running so much slower than localhost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, heroku

I created a simple stock screener (filters out stocks given certain criteria) in Rails.  On my localhost the stocks update instantly, but on Heroku it can take anywhere from 10-15 seconds before the stock list is updated.

My Heroku app is here: http://fruthscreener.herokuapp.com/
Github is here: github dot com/anfruth/Fruth_Screener_Rails

The code involved in updating the queries can be found in the user_stocks model and in the stocks controller under def create.

Any ideas why this is happening and suggestions as to how to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: This is a reasonable thing to ask a question about, but there's not enough information with which to answer it, save your entire codebase.  Please try to narrow it down and paste snippets of your code rather than asking people to go through your github repo -- or take it to codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5):

Not slow for me

--

**Heroku**

The only thing which will slow Heroku down is if your db connection is "off-site"

We've had apps before which ran super slowly due to the case that the database provider was a different host, in a different country.

Heroku [runs on AWS](https://www.heroku.com/policy/security#data_centers), meaning it will run super fast *if* you have all the dependencies in the same data-center. One of the drawbacks of using one of these powerful "cloud" hosting providers is they need to keep all requests *local* to help their system run quickly; hence if your DB is "off-site", it will slow it down profusely.

You must remember that Rails apps can't run unless they have a db connection; so if your connectivity is slow, your app's performance is going to be hit hard

-

**Postgres**

If your app is running slow on Heroku, the best thing to do is to make sure you're using Heroku's [`postgres`](https://www.heroku.com/postgres) database. This is deployed on Heroku's AWS cloud, meaning it's on the same network as your app, hence allowing it to run as quickly as possible

You'll need to change your app's `database` connection to the new `production` server like this:

```
#config/database.yml
production:
  .... #-> your Heroku db details here
```

This will allow you to run `heroku run rake db:migrate` after you push this new code to Heroku - which should define the db structure for you, allowing you to populate it as you wish

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you would benefit from using New Relic or another performance management package for Heroku in order to find out what is causing you trouble exactly.  The free tier of New Relic should be enough to get you started.

By the way, if your app is a Heroku free tier app (one single web dyno), then your dyno will go to sleep when not in use, and you may be encountering dyno spin-up costs, which are frequently about 5-15 seconds.  Repeat the same query several times in several minutes and see if the slowness persists for every request, or only the first one.